# Derivative of point normal vector with respect to vertices

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

I have a problem which needs to compute the derivative of point normal vector with respect to the vertices of a mesh. As shown in here (https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MeshDifferentialGeometry.pdf)

the point normal at a vertex ${\bf{v}}_i$ is, 
$$
{\bf{n}}_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n} {{({\bf{e}}_j \times {\bf{e}}_{j+1})}}/||{{\bf{e}}_j \times {\bf{e}}_{j+1}}||_2
$$
where ${j\in N(i)}$ is 1-ring neighborhood around the vertex ${\bf{v}}_i$ and ${\bf{e}}_j={\bf{v}}_i-{\bf{v}}_j$ is edge which connects ${\bf{v}}_i$ and neighboring vertex ${\bf{v}}_j$. My question is that how can i derive the $\frac{d{\bf{n}}_i}{d{\bf{v}}_i}$?